# Archive of custom post type not showing

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a parent theme and a child theme (spacious).

I have made a custom post type called "job-openings".
a single page (using `single-job-openings.php` in the child theme folder) - which works fine, at `www.domain.com/job-openings/test-job-opp/`

but the archive page (using `archive-job-openings.php` in the child theme folder) does not work at `www.domain.com/job-openings/` - i get a 'Page not Found' error.

i have tried to re-submit the 'permalinks' section under settings (as well as changing to default and then back to post name), but that has not helped.

Anyone know what the issue could be?

Thanks

This is the code i used in the `functions.php` file to add the post type:

```
    add_action( 'init', 'create_position_post_type' );

    function create_position_post_type() {
        register_post_type( 'job-openings',
        array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Job Openings' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Job Opening' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'job-openings'),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_position' => '100',
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),
        )
        );
    }
```

Comment: Try using `'has_archive' => true`  in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because you're missing `has_archive`

Something like this

`'public' => true,
'has_archive' => true,`